# Is it possible to create seperate permission levels based on different columns in a sharepoint online custom list?

Tags: custom-list

I need a custom excell type form where only admin can edit specific fields and any other employee can edit specific fields.
for example, suppose that i have a custom list with column names: location, problem and remedy.
basically only admin can specify the location of the problem, and an employee can go and and check that problem. after that problem is solved the employee will specify the problem and its remedy by editing in the same form. But that employee cannot change the location of the problem, only admin can do that.

Comment: you can hide certain column using javascript, for instance is a user is not in a particular user group, the column (Location) can be hidden from the form.  Therefore the user can not update it.  I have the impressions that you need to read up on Permissions first though, in order to understand how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible. Sharepoint Platform does't have an field level security. You can do some smoke and mirror solution with Infopath\PowerAPp but nothing will stop user from creating a custom view and modify the content directly in the list. For some cases such solution is enough.